# Widgets structure

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to make a hex editor using the Qt framework (under pyqt for quick testing).

My goal is to have a GUI similar with well known hex editor like [hexed.it](https://hexed.it)

Hex edit Screenshot:
[image: Hex edit Screenshot]

Like you can see in the picture, there is 3 parts:

- The offset of the line (left)
- The actual hex data (center)
- The ASCII representation of the data (right)

I want to be able to hide/remove all these part individually.

I know how to create custom widget, model, view, or delegate but I don't know what I should create for these 3 parts.

Should I create 3 separate views and try to make sure there sizes are the same?
Should I create 1 big widget and draw everything in it?
Or is there an other solution I didn't think of?

Basically, how would you structure all of it?

Comment: I suggest you to rephrase the title of this post, as it's very vague and generic, while the title should always try to clearly summarize the contents of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a QTableView with a custom model, and set the margins using [`setViewportMargins()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#setViewportMargins).

Note that margins are always reset by all QAbstractItemView subclasses whenever [`updateGeometries()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#updateGeometries) is called (everytime the view is resized, or something in the headers change), you need to override that method and reset the margins again.

Then, since painting in scroll areas cannot happen outside the *viewport*, you have to create widgets that will paint what you need.

In the following implementation this happens by using an event filter that will catch the paintEvents on those widgets and then will actually paint the contents based on the current data.

Note that in order to correctly achieve this, the following aspects are important:

- those widgets *must* be created at the very beginning of the `__init__`, since `updateGeometries` is called even when the model is set;
- you need to connect the vertical scrollbar `valueChanged` to the respective `update` functions, so that the contents are always correctly updated;
- this is a very simple implementation that doesn't take into account many aspects: for instance, there's no "middle space" between the eight and ninth column;

[image: test screenshot]

```
class HexModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    # a simple model with random data contents
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.randomData = [randrange(32, 128) for i in range(500)]

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return 16

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.randomData) // 16 + 1

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            try:
                char = self.randomData[index.row() * 16 + index.column()]
                return '{:02X}'.format(char)
            except IndexError:
                return None
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            try:
                return self.randomData[index.row() * 16 + index.column()]
            except IndexError:
                return None
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter


class HexEdit(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.offsetWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.asciiWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.offsetWidget.installEventFilter(self)
        self.asciiWidget.installEventFilter(self)

        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Courier'))
        self.setModel(HexModel())

        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(30)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.offsetWidget.update)
        self.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.asciiWidget.update)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == event.Paint:
            if source == self.offsetWidget:
                self.paintOffset()
                return True
            elif source == self.asciiWidget:
                self.paintAscii()
                return True
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def paintOffset(self):
        top = self.indexAt(QtCore.QPoint())
        if top.isValid():
            top = top.row()
        else:
            top = 0
        sectionHeight = self.verticalHeader().defaultSectionSize()
        count = self.viewport().height() // sectionHeight
        rect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, self.offsetWidget.width(), sectionHeight)
        offset = self.verticalHeader().offset() % sectionHeight
        rect.translate(0, -offset)
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self.offsetWidget)
        for i, row in enumerate(range(top, top + count + 1)):
            qp.drawText(rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignRight, 
                '{:08x}'.format(row * 16))
            rect.translate(0, sectionHeight)

    def paintAscii(self):
        top = self.indexAt(QtCore.QPoint())
        if top.isValid():
            top = top.row()
        else:
            top = 0
        sectionHeight = self.verticalHeader().defaultSectionSize()
        count = self.viewport().height() // sectionHeight
        rect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, self.asciiWidget.width(), sectionHeight)
        offset = self.verticalHeader().offset() % sectionHeight
        rect.translate(0, -offset)
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self.asciiWidget)
        model = self.model()
        for i, row in enumerate(range(top, top + count + 1)):
            chars = ''
            for column in range(16):
                char = model.index(row, column).data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
                if char is None:
                    chars += '.'
                else:
                    chars += chr(char)
            qp.drawText(rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft, chars)
            rect.translate(0, sectionHeight)

    def updateGeometries(self):
        super().updateGeometries()
        charSize = self.fontMetrics().width('0')
        margin = max(2, self.frameWidth() * 2)
        self.offsetWidget.resize(charSize * 8 + margin, self.viewport().height())
        self.asciiWidget.resize(charSize * 16 + margin, self.viewport().height())
        self.setViewportMargins(
            self.offsetWidget.width() + margin, 0, 
            self.asciiWidget.width() + margin, 0)
        self.offsetWidget.move(margin, margin)
        self.asciiWidget.move(self.viewport().geometry().right() + margin, margin)

    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = super().sizeHint()
        margin = max(2, self.frameWidth() * 2)
        width = self.offsetWidget.width() + self.asciiWidget.width()
        width += margin * 4 + self.verticalScrollBar().width()
        width += self.horizontalHeader().defaultSectionSize() * 16
        hint.setWidth(width)
        return hint
```